# Django RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no faculty. python (im getting this error i have also posted the screenshot of error) below code

Tags: python, django, flask

`HI im new to python i got a project from github when i run it it says RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
GitHub link = https://github.com/venugopalkadamba/Face_Verification_based_Attendance_system

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def takeAttendence(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = {
            'branch':request.POST['branch'],
            'year': request.POST['year'],
            'section':request.POST['section'],
            'period':request.POST['period'],
            'faculty':request.user.faculty
            }
        if Attendence.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()),branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],period = details['period']).count() != 0 :
            messages.error(request, "Attendence already recorded.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            students = Student.objects.filter(branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'])
            names = Recognizer(details)
            for student in students:
                if str(student.registration_id) in names:
                    attendence = Attendence(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty, 
                    Student_ID = str(student.registration_id), 
                    period = details['period'], 
                    branch = details['branch'], 
                    year = details['year'], 
                    section = details['section'],
                    status = 'Present')
                    attendence.save()
                else:
                    attendence = Attendence(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty, 
                    Student_ID = str(student.registration_id), 
                    period = details['period'],
                    branch = details['branch'], 
                    year = details['year'], 
                    section = details['section'])
                    attendence.save()
            attendences = Attendence.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()),branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],period = details['period'])
            context = {"attendences":attendences, "ta":True}
            messages.success(request, "Attendence taking Success")
            return render(request, 'attendence_sys/attendence.html', context)        
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/home.html', context)

def searchAttendence(request):
    attendences = Attendence.objects.all()
    myFilter = AttendenceFilter(request.GET, queryset=attendences)
    attendences = myFilter.qs
    context = {'myFilter':myFilter, 'attendences': attendences, 'ta':False}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/attendence.html', context)


def facultyProfile(request):
    faculty = request.user.faculty
    form = FacultyForm(instance = faculty)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/facultyForm.html', context)
```

can any one help me identify the issue

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AN9n.png)`

Comment: You apparently have a user without a `Faculty`, or where you perhaps removed the faculty...

Comment: Add **Faculty** model code in question

Comment: i have linked the project file. Can u identify the error and post the screenshot